# Android: Same code has change behaviour from one day to an other

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm in shock. I use a snippet of code based on the book Android Recipes 4th Edition to download a code that I need which a zip file. Today, I updated that zip file, and the suddenly, I noticed that my code wasn't working (That shouldn't make sense because server side and client side are not related)

Well, I start to debug, and even try to remake the snippet, but the situation it's the same, the Activity is not doing part of the code, isn't entering onResume.

Does anyone know anything about what could it be? Thanks.

```
    package com.example.juanse.secgps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;

public class DescargaCiudad extends Activity {
    private static final String DL_ID = "downloadId";
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private DownloadManager dm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!prefs.contains(DL_ID)) {
//Start the download
            Uri resource = Uri.parse("http://www.adeter.org/zipSample.zip");
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(resource);
//Set allowed connections to process download
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
//Finding a place to be saved

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/omw", "zipSample.zip");

//Display in the notification bar
            request.setTitle("Download Sample");
            long id = dm.enqueue(request);
//Save the unique id
            prefs.edit().putLong(DL_ID, id).commit();
        } else {
            //Download already started, check status
            queryDownloadStatus();
        }
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            queryDownloadStatus();
        }
    };

    private void queryDownloadStatus() {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(prefs.getLong(DL_ID, 0));
        Cursor c = dm.query(query);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int status = c.getInt(
                    c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
            switch (status) {
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
//Do nothing, still in progress
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
//Done, display the image
                    try {
                        //bajado con e
                        String ZipFileLocation = "/sdcard/omw/zipSample.zip";
                        String unzipLocation = "/sdcard/omw/";


                        // Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
                        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ZipFileLocation);
                        // Extracts all files to the path specified
                        zipFile.extractAll(unzipLocation);
                        // Call the map main activity to draw the points
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMap.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
//Clear the download and try again later
                    dm.remove(prefs.getLong(DL_ID, 0));
                    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Just Clean Build your app again .... its working perfectly .... file Downloaded First .... in second call  in on resume always else Block executes..

Comment: Have done and doesn't work. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I think your prefs have already DL_ID, so if you removed your previously downloaded file from download manager, you will not be able to execute any part.
Check once

Comment: With this configuration already worked for moths, Also is how is followed in the book I mentioned above,